# What permissions/rights for Very Sleepy profiling?

Tags: c++, process, profiling, rights-management, verysleepy

I would like allow a user to use of Very Sleepy, without give him administrators rights.

Without admin' rights, he can launch Very Sleepy then launch an application with the software to profile it. But he can't see active process to launch a profiling on them.

Do you know a solution ?

PS : In particular, in sources, Very Sleepy use windows.h, process.h & winnt.h

Comment: seems more appropriate for ServerFault..?

Comment: Good idea ! I didn't know ServerFault, I'll go to also ask my question on this website ;)

Comment: No answer on ServerFault and the Very Sleepy dev' doesn't know either